# Redis `TIME` Command in Cluster Mode

Tags: go, redis, cluster-computing

I need to use `TIME Command` in Redis, but I’m in the Cluster mode. Now my question is that, what is the source of the Time which I get from the system’s response in Cluster mode ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would imagine since its the current servers time, you would get the time of the machine in the cluster the command hits

Comment: Which server? I have 20 master nodes and other ...

Comment: do u have separate time zone for each node?

Comment: No, same time zone, But It's important that the time difference is less than 10ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I need to use synchronize time between servers and I thought to use `Redis **TIME** Command`, but now after some research, I think NTP can resolve my problem.

> A time difference of less than 128ms between server and client is
> required to maintain NTP synchronization. The typical accuracy on the
> Internet ranges from about 5ms to 100ms, possibly varying with network
> delays

Answer (score 0):

If accuracy between nodes is important, you should really run a local NTP server somewhere very close to them.

This gives the general idea -  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp
[google for ntp & your O/S]

Make one node your local time server & sync with your preferred NTP provider on the internet [google for well known ntp servers]

Sync your local nodes to the local ntp time node you created. This ought to give you better than 1ms latency depending on your infrastructure.

All your local nodes  should be within a few ms of each other & all the same difference from the network source.